# Is there a way to perform a side effect on Observables for both next and error callbacks in a single line?

Tags: rxjs

What I'm trying to achieve is performing a side effect, something like hiding a progress bar or a loading spinner when an observable completes or throws an error, but i would like to do it in only one place if such thing is possible.

Ex.

Current implementation:

```js
myObservable.subscribe(next=>{ 
 stopLoader();
 }, error=>{
 stopLoader();
});
```

Desired implementation:

```js
myObservable
.pipe(<some-unknown-operator-to-me-that-might-exist>(_=> stopLoader()))
.subscribe(......);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `finalize` operator

```
myObservable.pipe( ..... , finalize(()=>stopLoader()))
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what i was looking for. I knew there had to be an operator like that.